# Jquery Dialog UI with two div in two different columns

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have two HTML Div, I want to create a Jquery UI dialog where each of each are displayed in two different columns. Uptill, I am able to display one div in one of the UI box when a button is clicked.

```
 <script>


    $(function () {
        $("#dialog1").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: {
                effect: "fold",
                duration: 500
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "scale",
                duration: 500
            }


        });


        if (document.getElementById("viewcheck").value == "true" && document.getElementById("servercheck").value == "true") {
            $("#dialog1").dialog("open");



        }
    });
```

```
<div id="dialog1" title="Basic dialog">
    @Model.Message
```

Something Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the positions of your dialogs (http://jqueryui.com/position/) and then confirm if the two dialogs open at the same time.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question. Kindly have a look. I want it inside one dialog only.